# Une traduction pour « opmerken als zodanig »

Tags: traduction, expressions, néerlandais

Le néerlandais permet une tournure que je vous décris ici. C’est un peu comme *apercevoir quelque chose sans le reconnaitre*. Je donnerai aussitôt quelques exemples, le meilleur moyen pour expliquer cette tournure.

On pourrait l’utiliser si on voit une chose conçue de façon à ce que personne ne puisse la reconnaitre. Si une bête est entièrement verte pour mieux se cacher dans la verdure, il est pensable qu’on la voit, mais on n’est pas conscient que c'est un être vivant, parce qu’elle semble de faire partie d’une plante. Alors y a-t-il une tournure plus adroite que celle-ci :
« J’avais vu cette araignée mais je ne l’ai pas reconnue. » ?

Il ne s’agit pas toujours d’une chose sous déguisement. Un livre peut se trouver parmi beaucoup de livres qui portent la même couverture, et cela peut rendre difficile de distinguer ce que l’on cherche. Si on a inconsciemment vu le livre recherché et on s’en avise plus tard, on pourrait aussi se servir de la façon de dire ci-dessus.

Connaissez-vous une expression française qui équivaut à ce que j’esquisse ici ?

**Ajustement**. Je suis désolé que cette question fût dénuée des données requises pour la répondre. Il faillait dire que les choses suivants pour la complétude :
La recherche d’une chose n’est pas de composant requis.
Le sujet, la personne, ne pressent pas nécessairement qu’il y a quelque chose qu’il n’aperçoit pas.
Voici encore exemple, dont j’espère qu’il rend des choses plus claires.

Les souris couinent assez souvent, mais un tel bruit est très peu « reconnu » comme le bruit d’un souris, parce qu’il y a beaucoup d’oiseau qui font des sons semblables.

Ici, rien ne laisse penser que quelqu’un cherche une souris, et le pressentiment qu’elle soit auprès du sujet de la phrase manque aussi, ce qui doit être souligné. S’il n’y pas de meilleure manière de dire que celle qui se sert de « reconnaitre », alors dites moi et je ferai avec.

Comment: Chez moi on dit « caché comme le nez au milieu de la figure » et plutôt pour se moquer de quelqu'un. Mais je ne l'ai jamais entendu ailleurs.

Comment: @Evpok Je n'emploie pas l'expression dans le même sens que toi  (celui décrit par le PO)

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement j'emploierais l'expression: "Sentir la présence de quelque chose". Par exemple :
 « J'avais senti la présence d'une araignée ».

L'emploi de "sentir" montre que l'on ne réussit pas à localiser l'objet en question, "la présence" renforce le côté flou de la perception.

Comment: Il ne s’agit pas toujours de quelqu’un qui est au courant de la présence d’une chose pendant qu’il cherche. C’est pourquoi vôtre réplique ne me contente pas tout à fait. J’ajouterai encore un exemple en espérant qu’il éclaire le sens de « opmerken als zodanig »